# Ionic Pro Package - Application error on launching APK

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I have an Ionic Pro account, and I have pushed up a build of my Ionic application, which at least works on my local machine (haven't been able to try it out on an emulator yet).

I have then used the Ionic Package tool to generate an APK so that I can install the app onto my Android device. The package tool built an APK successfully.

However, on launching the app I simply get a dialog box which says,

> Application Error
>
> net: FILE_ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> (file:///android_asset/www/index/html)

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Or perhaps any ideas on how best to diagnose this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily diagnose this issue if you debug your `apk` on the device using CLI.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```